# Is there a pythonic way to apply the same operation on two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a couple dataframes and am looking for a more pythonic, elegant way to apply the same operations/methods on each dataframe.

If I was working with 3+ dataframes, I could loop through a list or dictionary. But for two DFs it looks excessive. How can I simplify the following example?

```
df1.columns = map(str.lower, df1.columns)
df2.columns = map(str.lower, df2.columns)
```

Comment: There isn't really another option. It's either the 2 lines or the loop

Comment: These two lines of code are elegant and pythonic.

Comment: **df1, df2 = (map(str.lower,df) for df in [df1, df2])** Hope this helps

Comment: you can use `for df in (df1, df2): df.rename(columns=str.lower, inplace=True)` but for two dataframes that is pythonic enough

Comment: As an aside, pandas way of doing this is `df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alternatively use:

```
df1.columns, df2.columns = df1.columns.str.lower(), df2.columns.str.lower()
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop would be the same for 2 (or even 1) data frame as it would be for 3 or more.

```
for x in [df1, df2]:
    x.columns = map(str.lower, x.columns)
```

Whether that is an improvement over your existing two lines of code is a matter of opinion.